# How to redirect from non-www to www with correct page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to 301-redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` by `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Problem: `my-site.com/contact.html` redirects to `www.example.com/index.php` instead of `www.example.com/contact.html`.

How can I accomplish that?

**UPDATE**: this is the complete `.htaccess` for my Joomla-site (comments stripped):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

###### this is the code in question...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example/$1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

# take care of sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1&format=html [L]
```

I moved my two lines up just below `RewriteEnigine On` - but had the same problem again. Clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem: example.com/contact.html redirects to www.example.com/index.php instead of www.example.com/contact.html.

I'm going to guess that you have other rules in your htaccess file, one that routes everything to index.php. You need to make sure that *your redirect rule is **before** any other rule that you have*.

---

After checking your htaccess file, you need to add an `L` flag at the end of your first rule:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
```

Because without it, the redirect gets applied even if the first rule gets applied (e.g. it gets rewritten to `index.php` with a 403 response waiting in the queue).

Comment: @michi try adding an `L` flag to the first rule (next to the `F`)

Comment: Yes! this did the trick! Would you edit your answer to include the solution? I hope I am not asking too much, but **why** does it work? Thank you, Jon!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly uncomment line

```
# RewriteBase / //Remove #
```

Below the above line write this code

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm already in the wrong for asking for clarification but you can just delete this.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]

I see you added an exclamation point and I've seen this redirect elsewhere without it. What does the exclamation point do in this case or is that incorrect?

Have a great day.